# "sales_order_place_after" event not working in magento2

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, magento-2.0

I first used `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` then used event `sales_order_place_after` but secound event is not working..any idea? scope is global.

ex- **Company/Vendors/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_grid_vendors_customer" instance="Company\Vendors\Observer\AddVendorOrders" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer/AddVendorOrders.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Vendors\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AddVendorOrders implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
        die('testing);
      }
}
```

Comment: Any error are generate in log, Have you checked?

Comment: nop..i solve one error now not get quote details..code is  $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
  $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
  $customerEmail = $quote->getCustomerEmail();                                                not get $customerEmail..how to get?

Comment: you can do it using $order->getCustomerEmail()

Comment: tx.. how to get quote data..ex- status.

Comment: you can fetch using $order->getData()

Comment: ya but i don't get above i mention this thing bro.

Comment: you can just set inside execute method like, $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); and you can get all data related to order

Comment: Quote data also get??

Comment: after you can $order->getData() you can get all field from this

Comment: sorry not get Quote in set custom field in array..only get Quote id.

Comment: have you checked getData() inside $quote->getData() whick field are display?

Comment: perfect...thanx..bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just find from **`getData()`** method,

check using ,

```
$quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId()); 
echo "<pre>";print_R($quote->getData());
```

Now you can check all field of quote object and get field based on your requirements.